# flutter network image gif is not animated

Tags: flutter, gif

I'm using this code and it works but the GIF images coming from the network are not animated, they are shown by their first frame.

```
ListTile(
                            tileColor: Colors.white,
                            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImageWithRetry(snapshot.data[index]['avatar_url']),
                            ),
                            title: Text(snapshot.data[index]['user_name']),
                          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is coming from NetworkImageWithRetry().

At the time of this posting this, NetworkImageWithRetry() doesn't support GIF images. It only shows the first frame of the GIF.